# Select Entity where Hibernate OneToOne association is not present

Tags: hibernate

I have two classes with a bi-directional @OneToOne mapping to each other.

```
Class A {
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy, mappedBy="a")
private B b;
}

Class B {
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.Eager)
private A a;
}
```

I need to write code to retrieve all instance of B which to do not have an instance of A associated with them. I also need to write a similar query for all A which have no B.

I have tried:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(B.class)
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("a")
```

but this seems to always return null. Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work, for both directions:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(B.class, "b");
criteria.createAlias("b.a", "a", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("a.id"));
```

Comment: Works. Couldn't figure out why isNull was adding the null to the wrong property in my query with a OneToOne.

Comment: As `Criteria.LEFT_JOIN` is deperciated now can use `criteria.createAlias("b.a", "a", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);`

Answer (score 1):

There is a documented problem in Hibernate, which says that ["The query language IS NULL syntax won't work with a one-to-one association!"](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_The_query_language_IS_NULL_syntax_wont_work_with_a_onetoone_association)

Also, there is a pending Jira on the same issue [JIRA](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1057)

Till this gets fixed, the workaround provided by JB Nizet works great.