# Hibernate criteria query for parent-childs relationship where parent is null (get root entries)

Tags: java, hibernate, parent-child, criteria, isnull

I have a simple parent-child relationship witin the same class. I like to get all instances where no parent exists (= NULL).Means the "root" categories.

I need to use criteria query and can not use HQL or SQL. Due an [issue with Relationship and "isNull" Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649754/select-entity-where-hibernate-onetoone-association-is-not-present) it seems that the criteria query can not be "normally" be used as expected and require some trick. Anybody has any hints which I can try?

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy(value="pos")
    private List<Category> childs = new ArrayList<Category>();
    ...
}
```

If I use the following criteria query construct I get strange result back. I get multiple times the same category instances instead just the "root" ones.

```
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Category.class, "c");
    c.add(Restrictions.isNull("c.parent"));
    List<Category> rootCategories = c.list(); 
    for(Category category : rootCategories) {
        logger.info(category);
    }
```

I tried already some constructs with aliases but no luck. Left Join or inner join will not work ;(

```
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Category.class, "c");
    c.createAlias("c.parent", "p", JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
    c.add(Restrictions.isNull("p.id"));
    List<Category> rootCategories = c.list(); 
    for(Category category : rootCategories) {
        logger.info(category);
    }
```

In case I use HQL (which isunfortunately no option for my issue) it works perfectly

```
    List<Category> rootCategories = session.createQuery("FROM Category c where c.parent is null order by c.pos").list();
```

Thank you for any hints in advance

Comment: The issue you mentioned shouldn't affect many-to-one relationships. I think you should turn on debug logging and see what sql statements Hibernate generates. And what exactly do you mean by "Left Join will not work"?

Comment: If I keep it EAGER on the childs attribute mapping then the sql statements look like this `select this_.id as id1_2_1_, this_.parent_id as parent_i2_2_1_, childs2_.parent_id as parent_i2_2_3_, childs2_.id as id1_2_3_, childs2_.id as id1_2_0_, childs2_.parent_id as parent_i2_2_0_ from Category this_ left outer join Category childs2_ on this_.id=childs2_.parent_id where this_.parent_id is null`. This query returns mutliple time the same instance is not distinct.

Comment: If I change the child mapping to LAZY then it generates a different sql statement which works, only the single instances get returned `select this_.id as id1_2_1_, this_.parent_id as parent_i2_2_1_, category2_.id as id1_2_0_, category2_.parent_id as parent_i2_2_0_ from Category this_ left outer join Category category2_ on this_.parent_id=category2_.id where this_.parent_id is null`. This EAGER / LAZY should not make any difference looksfor me like a bug.

Comment: With "Left Join not work" I mean in case an id is null you can not use inner join so you need to use an outer join as the sql statements above show. Sorry when I was unprecise.

Comment: By the way I am using Hibernate 4.3.10